# How should I smooth the outliers on a 3D surface?

Tags: r, smoothing

I have taken a `3D` surface from package `akima`.

```
library(akima)
data(akima)
matrix_1 <- akima::interp(x = akima$x, y = akima$y, z = akima$z)
persp(matrix_1$x, matrix_1$y, matrix_1$z)
```

[image: 3D Surface]

To this surface, I have added some outlier data points.

```
# Add outliers
akima$x = c(akima$x, 11, 12, 13)
akima$y = c(akima$y, 11, 12, 13)
akima$z = c(akima$z, 70, 80, 75)
matrix_2 <- akima::interp(x = akima$x, y = akima$y, z = akima$z)
persp(x = matrix_2$x, y = matrix_2$y, z = matrix_2$z)
```

The new surface looks like -
[image: 3D Surface with outliers]

Now, I want to smooth these outliers to the original surface without disturbing the original surface but I could not accomplish that. Here is what I have tried and I will appreciate it if someone can show me how to do this.

```
# Trying to smooth and remove outliers
library(mgcv)
mod <- gam(z ~ te(x) + te(y) + ti(x, y), data = akima)
akima$new = predict(mod, akima)

matrix_3 <- akima::interp(x = akima$x, y = akima$y, z = akima$new)
persp(matrix_3$x, matrix_3$y, matrix_3$z)
```

Here is the surface after smoothing with `gam`, which is not the expected output. The expected output is the first graph with the new values of outliers.

[image: Incorrect 3D surface disturbed by outliers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a statistical question than a computing question, but one approach would be to look at the size of the residuals from your `gam()` fit, and only modify the `z` coordinate if the residual is particularly large.

For example:

```r
library(akima)
data(akima)

akima$x <- c(akima$x, 11, 12, 13)
akima$y <- c(akima$y, 11, 12, 13)
akima$z <- c(akima$z, 70, 80, 75)

# Trying to smooth and remove outliers
library(mgcv)
#> Warning: package 'mgcv' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Warning: package 'nlme' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> This is mgcv 1.8-39. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
mod <- gam(z ~ te(x) + te(y) + ti(x, y), data = akima)
akima$pred <- predict(mod, akima)
akima$resid <- akima$z - akima$pred
hist(akima$resid)
```

[image]

```r
akima$new <- ifelse(akima$resid < 25, akima$z, akima$pred)
matrix_3 <- akima::interp(x = akima$x, y = akima$y, z = akima$new)
persp(matrix_3$x, matrix_3$y, matrix_3$z)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I just chose the cutoff of 25 by eye; if you want to use a more automatic method, you'll need to ask about that on stats.stackexchange.com .  You could also iterate a bit, to get better predictions without including the outliers.  Again, that's a stats question.